# AWS Aurora Serverless MySQL hanging periocically for no apparent reason

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I am getting a lot of times where my Aurora Serverless MySQL database will just suddenly lockup with a lot of waiting for "table metadata lock" and waiting for "table level lock",

When that happens, the entire application is not able to access the locked tables, and no matter how long I wait, those locks does not get freed up. I need to sign into the database from the rds query editor and manually kill the threads.

This has not happened when I was running my own MySQL server installation, only on Aurora Serverless.

There are no database transactions used in the system, and the database is set to auto commit after every queries.

Is there something I can do about this to stop this from happening?

[image]

Comment: We are facing a very similar issue right now. May I ask, do you have any update to this since it is 7 months ago? Anything that helps is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Nope. I have reached out to Aws support and they seems to have solved it in the backend. I no longer encounter this issue now

Comment: FYI: We switched away from Aurora Serverless to plain Aurora RDS. It just didn't work out. Serverless version was behaving in uncontrolled manners...